# Round Rect Button

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, button, rounding

So when I use the iphone 5 simulator for xcode my round react buttons are all in the right position. But when I use the iphone 4 simulator the buttons move around and get deformed. how can I get this to not happen? I want the buttons to stay in the same place no matter what version of phone i use. So an example would be, I position 5 buttons verticaly on the left side of the screen. When I use the iphone 5 simulator the buttons are in the right place. I use the iphone 4 simulator and the buttons are all smooshed. Thanks

Comment: Are you using Storyboards? Are you using AutoLayout? Are you using AutoResizing masks? Show some code.

Comment: Do I just go to simulated metrics. and just select each screen size and design the storyboard for each one?

Comment: You can design a storyboard for each or you can properly use Autolayout to tell it how you'd like to resize the buttons. right now they probably have a height constraint on them but what you want are margin constraints

Comment: ok cool. how could i do that?

Comment: Post a quick screenshot of the button in your storyboard as well as the inspector on the right showing its constraints.